# Login Servlet not working

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

for some reason I'm getting an error 500 since I transferred my eclipse web project to another computer. My login servlet is not working, please help! There's nothing wrong with the code, since it was working fine on my other computer, but now it's not working. When I start the server it gives an error 500, and then after everytime I try to login, it will give error 404.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Login" method="post">
<h1>
Login
</h1>
 <b>Employee ID:</b> <br>
 <input type="text"name="employee_id"><br><br>
<b>Password:</b><br>
<input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login"><br><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Login.java servlet

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String employee_id = request.getParameter("employee_id");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");    

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
        session.setAttribute("employeeid", employee_id);

        if(ValidateLogin.user(employee_id, password)) { 
            RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("PersonalInfoOutput");
            rs.forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
           out.print("Employee ID or Password is incorrect. Please try again.");
           RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
           rs.include(request, response);
        }
    }  

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
               processRequest(request, response);
          }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
               processRequest(request, response);
          }


        }
```

ValidateLogin.java servlet

```
import java.sql.*;
public class ValidateLogin
{
    public static boolean user(String employee_id, String password)
    {
        boolean st = false;
        try { 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from payroll_system.employee_login where employeeID = ? and pwd = ?");
            ps.setString(1, employee_id);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
             st = rs.next();

         }catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
             return st;                 
      } 
}
```

ERROR:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class Login

type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class Login

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class Login
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Login
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Stupid question: did you try to recompile the project?

Comment: Looks like your war is missing some classes or jars. You say you've moved from one computer to another, have you got all the same dependent jars on the new computer? Have you considered using something like maven to manage dependencies?

Comment: @sisyphus For some reason it's working now, just for no apparent reason, it started working....

Answer (score 0):

How are you deploying your application? Application server is not able to find your source as message clearly says it.
Tell us more about your code structure, deploying method and possibly web.xml.
You are right, it is not code issue, it is an environment issue.